# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.framework'

Tags: python, tensorflow

When i import tflearn in Python, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.framework', does someone know how to deal with this issue? Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn_init_.py", line 4, in 
from . import config
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 5, in 
from .variables import variable
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tflearn\variables.py", line 7, in 
from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope as contrib_add_arg_scope
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.framework'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message suggests the module is not installed/found.

For example, I do not have tflearn installed, but I have tensorflow installed.

```
>>> from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope
>>> import tflearn
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tflearn'
```

Try importing the whole tensorflow module and see if you are getting the same error. If so, try reinstalling the tensorflow module.

Comment: when i from tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops import add_arg_scope, it says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib.framework' just as i import tflearn, while i import tensorflow, no any errors.

Comment: What version of tensorflow have you got installed?

Comment: tensorflow-gpu            1.8.0            
tensorflow-tensorboard    1.5.1

Comment: If you're able to import the base tensorflow module, can you access add_arg_scope through the whole tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.add_arg_scope?

Comment: sorry i have no idea to do it

Comment: import tensorflow.contrib.framework.python.ops.add_arg_scope